# lint unit tests not running: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_PSI_CLASS_FILES_READING

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, junit, lint

I've wrote a lint rule to be used in my Android Studio project. It is already working successfully. However, the tests are not running. Everytime I try to execute the tests, I receive the following error:

```
USE_PSI_CLASS_FILES_READING
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_PSI_CLASS_FILES_READING
    at com.android.tools.lint.UastEnvironmentKt.createKotlinCompilerConfig(UastEnvironment.kt:310)
        at com.android.tools.lint.UastEnvironmentKt.access$createKotlinCompilerConfig(UastEnvironment.kt:1)
        at com.android.tools.lint.UastEnvironment$Configuration$Companion.create(UastEnvironment.kt:118)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.initializeProjects(LintCliClient.kt:1349)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintClient.performInitializeProjects$lint_api(LintClient.kt:1012)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.initializeProjectRoots(LintDriver.kt:570)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.doAnalyze(LintDriver.kt:485)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.doAnalyze$default(LintDriver.kt:474)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.kt:418)
        at com.android.tools.lint.checks.infrastructure.TestLintClient.analyze(TestLintClient.java:671)
        at com.android.tools.lint.checks.infrastructure.TestLintClient.analyze(TestLintClient.java:602)
        at com.android.tools.lint.checks.infrastructure.TestLintClient.checkLint(TestLintClient.java:349)
        at com.android.tools.lint.checks.infrastructure.TestLintRunner.checkLint(TestLintRunner.kt:229)
        at com.android.tools.lint.checks.infrastructure.TestLintRunner.run(TestLintRunner.kt:172)
        at com.android.tools.lint.checks.infrastructure.TestLintTask.run(TestLintTask.java:933)
```

Basically, the error occurs everytime I call the run method of lint() in my tests:

```
lint().files(classFile)
    .allowMissingSdk()
    .run()
    .expectWarningCount(1)
```

I executed the tests from Android Studio and by using `./gradlew lint-rules:test`. In both cases the same error arises.

Thanks for your help!